# Change out the source when running flash

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, video.js

We have a website that a client is using for a repository for their pdfs and videos. The client wants the videos to pop open in a modal. We are using fancy box to do this. We are having issues with IE 7 and IE 8. When the user clicks on the first video it loads with no problem. When they close the modal and click on a new video it pops up with the first video still showing. Here is our code! Any help would be grateful.

```
/* Video Fancybox */
$(".video").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'          :   'fade',
    'transitionOut'         :   'fade',
    'width'                 :   535,
    'height'                :   400,
    /*'showCloseButton'       :   false,*/
    'scrolling'             :   'no',
    'titleShow'             :   false,
    'type'                  :   'inline',
    'padding'               :   10,
    'onComplete'            :   initVideo,
    'onClosed'              :   killVideo
});
//Global Video variables
var videoPlayerInitialized = false;
var myPlayer;

function initVideo(selectedArray, selectedIndex, selectedOptions)
{

    var item = selectedArray[selectedIndex];
    var videoTitle = $(item).attr('data-video');

    if (videoPlayerInitialized != true){
        myPlayer = _V_("my_video");
        videoPlayerInitialized = true;
        myPlayer.ready(function(){
            playVideo(videoTitle);
        });
    } else {
        playVideo(videoTitle);
    }


}

function playVideo(videoTitle)
{
    myPlayer.src([
        { type: "video/mp4", src: videoTitle + ".mp4" },
        { type: "video/webm", src: videoTitle + ".webm" }
    ]);
    myPlayer.load();
    myPlayer.play();        
}

function killVideo()
{
    //var myPlayer = _V_("my_video");
    myPlayer.pause();
    //myPlayer.src('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your killVideo function only pauses the video. It doesn't actually remove anything. You'll want to destroy the old player as well to keep from loading players on top of each other. Or you could alternatively use one player but swap the src to remove the last one and load a new one in its place.